# URL and cname are not working

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, dns, web, cname

How to associate URL given by AWS with our domain name on AWS. we already have purchased a domain from elasticbeans.

i have tried to create record set and cname but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate your existing domain to Amazon R53. Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html).